# Assigning add-in permissions to a new user automatically, Exchange on Premises

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, office365-apps

We are trying to automate the process of giving permission to group of users to access add-in on **Prem**. The problem with [the method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/add-ins-for-outlook/manage-user-access-to-add-ins#use-exchange-online-powershell-to-limit-add-in-availability-to-specific-users) we are currently using  is, every time there is a new user added to the group we have to run this script.

```
$a = Get-DistributionGroupMember Marketing
Set-App -Identity ac83a9d5-5af2-446f-956a-c583adc94d5e -OrganizationApp -ProvidedTo SpecificUsers -UserList $a.Identity -DefaultStateForUser Enabled
```

We found that there is a new **Office365** Add-in Management console which lets you automate the process as mentioned in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/manage/manage-deployment-of-add-ins?view=o365-worldwide):

> Groups: If you assign an add-in to a group, users who are added to the group will automatically be assigned the add-in. And, when a user is removed from a group, the user loses access to the add-in

*We are trying to find a similar way of automating the process on **Prem** so that when new user is added to the group, he or she automatically gets the  permission of using add-in without the Admin running the above script again.*

*Not exactly sure if it makes any difference, but our environment is **hybrid**. We were also wondering if changes made on **Office365** can be synced back to on Prem.*

Answer (score 1):

You could find a list of all the attributes that are synced between on-premises and the cloud [right here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19901.dirsync-list-of-attributes-that-are-synced-by-the-azure-active-directory-sync-tool.aspx).

You could change the source authorization from Azure AD to local active Directory. Please see the following link:

[Change The Source Authority from Azure AD to Local Active Directory](https://newsignature.com/articles/change-the-source-authority-from-azure-ad-to-local-active-directory/)